# Unbounce open dialog by condition

Tags: unbounce

In Unbounce I have a form and a button 'submit'. It has an event 'Show Form confirmation dialog'

However, I would like to show this dialog in case my input field has "1" value. Otherwise, it should forward to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) .

How to make it?